# Azure File Share Backup

Tags: backup, azure

Howe are people backing up Azure Storage..
I see that you can :
1) Take storage snapshots but would need to write an azure function to perform the backup and purge operations.

2) Use azcopy or robocopy but wonder how well this works with potentially locked files.

3) Use a third party backup tool capable of backing up mounted shres, does anyone know of a good one?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I don't suggest you could use 3rd tool to backup file share. Currently, you could use share snapshots to backup your fileshare.

Answer (score 1):

You could use share snapshots to backup your file share.

You could check this [Announcing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-files-share-snapshots-public-preview/). If you want to create a share snapshots please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-snapshots).

Also, you could use Azcopy to copy files to another files, but it needs a script to do this.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more future help.

Answer (score 0):

Backup for File Share is still "Preview". See my Azure Cli Issue Report: [Stackoverflow Issue with Files](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5662)

The Current state: Does not seem to make sense to implement yet :-( 
I have allready a Groovy Script for Snapshots of Blobs (inlusive Restore) and thought it would also be easy to do for file shares.. Nope! There are some Issues:

Restoring a complete Share: Not Available.
Copy a Snapshot to another Destination: Not Available.

Hopefully it will be fixed soon....